# How do I put a local-storage item in an if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, local-storage

I'm working on some code that runs a function that detects if the local storage item `En` is equal to the string `"English"`. Is there any way I could put `En = "English"` inside the rules of an if statement?
My current code:

```
const En = "English"

document.getElementById("langEn").onclick = function() {remLangEn()};

function remLangEn() {
localStorage.setItem(lang, En);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps we haven't understood your question correctly,  but its a little strange that you know about `setItem` but not `getItem`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage.getItem(YourKeyName)`

You can read more about `localStorage.getItem` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)

inside if you can use something like:

```
if(localStorage.getItem(YourKeyName) === 'English'){
    //Do Something
}
```

Comment: I have just provided the code snippet not the actual code.